Why must the ntp server using the local clock use the default loopback ip (127.127.1.0) ？
It seems that the ntp server using the local clock must use the default loopback ip address(127.127.1.0).
If I use the local ethernet ip address for the ntp server as the source local clock, it just gets stuck in .INIT. state.

root@THCDB:/root# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.           5 l   53   64    1    0.000    0.000   0.000
root@THCDB:/root# grep ^server /etc/ntp.conf
server 127.127.1.0
root@THCDB:/root# sed -i '/^server/s/127.127.1.0/172.25.180.170/' /etc/ntp.conf
root@THCDB:/root# grep ^server /etc/ntp.conf
server 172.25.180.170
root@THCDB:/root# service ntpd restart
Shutting down ntpd:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting ntpd:                                             [  OK  ]
root@THCDB:/root# ntpq -pn
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 172.25.180.170  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
root@THCDB:/root# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 THCDB          .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000


The address 127.127.1.0 is a special address that denotes the local clock. The documentation at https://support.ntp.org/Support/UndisciplinedLocalClock#Single_Time_Server writes

Single Time Server
server 127.127.1.0
fudge  127.127.1.0 stratum 10


But also comments that, "The Undisciplined Local Clock should generally no longer be used." and goes on to recommend more modern alternatives.
Note that it's not the usual default loopback address 127.0.0.1.
